# Get list of values used on a `where` clause of a SQL Query

Tags: c#, sql-server, regex

I am trying to write a method that gets all values used on the `where` clause from a SQL query.

With a method like this:

```
List<string> GetAllValueInWhereClause(string sqlQuery){
//do something here and return
}
```

And a SQL Query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE Col1 = 'value1' AND Col2 = 2 OR Col3 <> 10 //more and more
```

Calling `GetAllValueInWhereClause("SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE Col1 = 'value1' AND Col2 = 2 OR Col3 <> 10")`  should return a list like this:

```
"value1"
2
10
```

I am trying to use a RegEx loop to get these values, but I am stuck.

Comment: your question is not clear. Try putting some expected output.

Comment: You need to be more specific. Is this a question about SQL syntax? How to dynamically create SQL syntax? C# code? The more info you can give, the easier it will be for people to help.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I think my question is clear enough :9. I just want to get all `value` on a `where` clause. I'm trying to use `Regex`, loop, and searching.. But it's still incomplete.
I dont understand why someone vote down my question

Comment: @mikenlanggio How have you setup your database context on c#? Are you using Entity Framework or ADO.NET. Can you show us those classes?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the classes from the namespace `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlParser.Parser`  to parse the sql statement.

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/parsing-t-sql-%E2%80%93-the-easy-way

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.sqlparser.parser?view=sql-smo-140.17283.0